# WPF codebehind does not know xaml names after switching to release

Tags: wpf, code-behind, release-mode

I have a WPF project, that after switching from Debug to Release version, Window1.xaml.cs is no longer familiar with names I defined in Window1.xaml.
Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: May be restart visual studio.

Comment: the code is pretty large, what do you think might be a good indicator?

Comment: here's Window1.xaml: http://pastebin.com/zPAkrs1f  and here's Window1.xaml.cs: http://pastebin.com/qk65Hqvs . it can't, for instance, understand the assignments, starting at line 263

Comment: It is customary to `Build` your project after changing the *Solution Configuration*.

Comment: You can also check if Build Action is set to 'Page' for your window.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I took at look at your pastebin code and I don't see any object named `MyPropertyGrid` in the XAML for Window1.xaml, so that would explain why the `MyPropertyGrid.something` calls in Window1.xaml.cs are saying they can't find the object